# Different email for Google Calendar API

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I've never used the Calendar API before. I'm working on a site for a client that offers pet services. I'm adding a booking system to the site with Google Calendar. But I can't seem to find a way to sync the calendar with the client's email instead of my email. Am I missing something?

Comment: so you made google account with your mail id ?

Comment: No. Currently, I'm setting up the credentials for the API. But I need to use the clients Gmail calendar.

Comment: you will need his creds to access calendar events.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the best way of setting it up. What happens if I need to add multiple users? Also, I'm not fond of the idea of having access to every client's Gmail account.

Comment: let me repeat the use case here - whenever a booking will be made by any customer on your clients site you want to add a event in your clients calendar, correct ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: you got some solution ?

Comment: Group groups. But I'm building my own solution instead.